# Macro for integrals, a problem with limits

Tags: xparse, xstring, integral

For a while now I have tried to come up with a macro, that can properly format inegrals (the way I like).
Aswell as giving it a few options that can be chosen e.g. `\int` and `\oint`.
So far there is a little problem arising in the code. It occurs when you choose the `\oint` by adding a `*` to the argument.
It does come with rigth integral, but the limits are a little wrong, since it contain too the `*` in the limits.

My Integral macro and an example is shown below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Int}{ >{\SplitList{;}}o}{%
    \IfValueT{#1}{\ProcessList{#1}{\IntLimitONE}}\,%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntLimitONE}{m}{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{*}{\oint\IntSplitLimits{#1}\!}{\int\IntSplitLimits{#1}\!}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntSplitLimits}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
    \IfValueT{#1}{\IntLimits#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntLimits}{mm}{%
    _{#1}^{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2\!\!}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
     \Int[a,b;*c,d;e,f] f(x,y,z) dxdydz \quad , \quad \Int[*a,b] f(x) dx
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have tried a few ways to counter this, none satisfy completely my needs.
One I tried was using the `\xstring` command `\StrSubstitute`

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntLimitONE}{m}{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{*}{}[\temp]%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{*}{\oint\IntSplitLimits{\temp}}{\int\IntSplitLimits{#1}}
}
```

It does indeed remove `*` from the limit, but the upper limit have been moved to the lower.

[image]

I cannot seem to understand what goes wrong here?
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does "fx." mean "for example"? The usual abbreviation in English is "e.g."

Comment: @TRiG yes it does. I thougt the abbreviation was fx :)

Comment: It's an oddity: Germans use an English abbreviation (f.e. or f.x.), while English-speakers use a Latin one. Germans naturally assume that the abbreviation they used is also used in English, but it really isn't.

Comment: @TRiG I don't know one German who uses 'f.e.' or 'f.x.'! I (and every other German I know) use 'bspw.'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is, that your `\temp` in the tried fix is read as one token and not parsed correctly. Inserting a few `\expandafter`s fixes this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Int}{ >{\SplitList{;}}o}{%
    \IfValueT{#1}{\ProcessList{#1}{\IntLimitONE}}\,%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntLimitONE}{m}{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{*}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{*}{}[\temp]\oint\expandafter\IntSplitLimits\expandafter{\temp}}{\int\IntSplitLimits{#1}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntSplitLimits}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
    \IfValueT{#1}{\IntLimits#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntLimits}{mm}{%
    _{#1}^{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{#2\!\!}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
     \Int[a,b;*c,d;e,f] f(x,y,z) dxdydz \quad , \quad \Int[*a,b] f(x) dx
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does work as intended, even if you misplace `*` [a*,b] :)

Comment: @SimonJensen well it is your fix not mine. I just inserted the `\expandafter`s.

Answer (score 11):

The outer part is good.

For deciding whether `*` appears, I use `\SplitArgument` for at most one occurrence of `*`; this will produce two arguments, the second of which is `-NoValue-` in case no asterisk appears.

The rest is just splitting at the comma.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Int}{>{\SplitList{;}}O{}}{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\IntA}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntA}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{*}}{m}}{%
  \IntB#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntB}{mm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {\IntC{\int}{#1}}% no *
   {\IntC{\oint}{#2}}% *
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntC}{m >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
  \IntD{#1}#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IntD}{mmm}{%
  #1_{#2}^{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Int[a,b;*c,d;e,f] f(x,y,z) \,dx\,dy\,dz \quad , \quad \Int[*a,b] f(x)\,dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `expl3` functions, you can split the argument at `;` and map on the sequence so obtained. If the item starts with `*`, discard it and choose `\oint`, otherwise choose `\int`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Int}{O{}}
 {
  \simon_int:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_simon_int_args_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \simon_int:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_simon_int_args_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_simon_int_args_seq
   {
    \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { \tl_head:n { ##1 } } { * }
     {% * case
      \simon_int_inner:Nf \oint { \tl_tail:n { ##1 } }
     }
     {% no * case
      \simon_int_inner:Nn \int { ##1 }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simon_int_inner:Nn
 {
  #1 \sb{ \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 1 } }
     \sp{ \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \simon_int_inner:Nn { Nf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Int[a,b;*c,d;e,f] f(x,y,z) \,dx\,dy\,dz \quad , \quad \Int[*a,b] f(x)\,dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

A variant that checks for the asterisk even if not leading the item:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Int}{O{}}
 {
  \simon_int:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__simon_int_args_seq
\tl_new:N \l__simon_int_ast_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \simon_int:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__simon_int_args_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__simon_int_args_seq
   {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { ##1 } { * }
     {% * case
      \tl_set:Nn \l__simon_int_ast_tl { ##1 }
      \tl_remove_once:Nn \l__simon_int_ast_tl { * }
      \simon_int_inner:NV \oint \l__simon_int_ast_tl
     }
     {% no * case
      \simon_int_inner:Nn \int { ##1 }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simon_int_inner:Nn
 {
  #1 \sb{ \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 1 } }
     \sp{ \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \simon_int_inner:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Int[a,b;*c,d;e*,f] f(x,y,z) \,dx\,dy\,dz \quad , \quad \Int[*a,b] f(x)\,dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I often upvote your excellent answer. I like the retina screenshot. :-)

Comment: It's no fun if you come around the corner and outsmart my answers by far :)

Comment: @Skillmon Nice attempt, but never mix `xstring` with `xparse`. `;-)` And the second version just defines two functions (plus a user level one) instead of four.

Comment: This works quite well, except if you misplace `*`, that I can live with :)

Comment: @SimonJensen The second code can be quite easily adjusted to check for a `*` anywhere.

Comment: @SimonJensen I added the variant for “misplaced `*`”