# Are there any packages which simplify typsetting integrals?

Tags: math-operators

The [physics package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf) has been instrumental for me in typesetting math cleanly and consistently (while following a lot of nuances of mathematical typesetting). But it does not have integral support. Does anyone know of a package which does? For example, it should add the differential (properly spaced and all) without me having to worry about it. I suppose I can make my own commands, but I was hoping someone already did all the work.

Comment: You could try the thing there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372276/macro-for-integrals-a-problem-with-limits/372282#372282

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [answer of @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372285/117050), I created a similar macro for myself, which also typesets the `dx` part.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\dd{\mathrm{d}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \Int { s o m o }
  {%
    \IfNoValueTF{ #2 }
      { \int }
      {
        \fiziks_int:nn { #1 } { #2 }
      }
    #3
    \IfNoValueF { #4 } { \fiziks_int_dx:n { #4 } }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__fiziks_int_args_seq
\tl_new:N \l__fiziks_int_ast_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \fiziks_int:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fiziks_int_args_seq { ; } { #2 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__fiziks_int_args_seq 
      {
        \tl_if_in:nnTF { ##1 } { * }
          {% * case
            \tl_set:Nn \l__fiziks_int_ast_tl { ##1 }
            \tl_remove_once:Nn \l__fiziks_int_ast_tl { * }
            \fiziks_int_inner:NnV \oint { #1 } \l__fiziks_int_ast_tl
          }
          {% no * case
            \fiziks_int_inner:Nnn \int { #1 } { ##1 }
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \fiziks_int_inner:Nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    #1
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #3 } 
      {
        \IfBooleanT { #2 } { \limits }
        \fiziks_int_inner_inner:Nx \sb { \clist_item:nn { #3 } { 1 } }
        \fiziks_int_inner_inner:Nx \sp { \clist_item:nn { #3 } { 2 } }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fiziks_int_inner:Nnn { NnV }
\cs_new:Npn \fiziks_int_inner_inner:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #2 } { #1 { #2 } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fiziks_int_inner_inner:Nn { Nx }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \fiziks_int_dx:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fiziks_int_args_seq { ; } { #1 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__fiziks_int_args_seq
      {
        \,\dd##1
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  \Int[0,T;0,a]{f^2}[t;x]
  \Int*[0,T;0,a]{f^2}[t;x]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]